# If Statement shows only once in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, foreach

i have a question regarding a foreach loop in PHP.
For some reason i seem to only get the last line echo'ed back this way and i am lost in where this problem lies. Whenever i check $onderdeeltje[1] and $selectedmodel in an echo inside the foreach loop and outside the IF statement it pastes them all out perfectly without any problems. It also shows that they are equal and the same and should react on the IF statement.. As soon as i compare the two inside IF statement it shows me only the last one. Whenever i remove the checkbox echo and replace it with anything such as echo "test"; it also shows me test only once. Could anybody shed some light on this? I have multiple (2 + this one) foreach loops like this in the same page that work perfectly but only this one seems to bug.

```
echo "<form method='post' action='formpie.php'>";

$onderdelen = file("onderdelen.txt");

foreach ($onderdelen as $onderdeel) 
{
    $onderdeeltje = explode(",", $onderdeel);

    if ($onderdeeltje[1] == $selectedmodel)
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='$onderdeeltje[0]'>$onderdeeltje[0]<br>";
    }
}

echo "</form>";
```

$selectedmodel will be: iPhone 3G and the text list is this:

```
Reparatie touchscreen €41.50,iPhone 3G
Reparatie Wi-Fi-antenne €50.00,iPhone 3G
Reparatie trilmodule €40.00,iPhone 3G
Reparatie sim slot €70.50,iPhone 3G
Reparatie oorluidspreker €46.00,iPhone 3G
```

It only shows: Reparatie oorluidspreker €46.00 as a checkbox.

Please help me out! :) Thanks in advance!

### -------------------------------------------------------------

**How to solve:**

It seems that there can be hidden spaces in the ouput that are not visible if these are pasted per line with things like `<br>` or in my case a list of repeated form checkbox values.

To fix this you simply have to trim the value before or inside the IF equal statement like so:

```
foreach ($onderdelen as $onderdeel) 
{
    $onderdeeltje = explode(",", $onderdeel);

    if (trim($onderdeeltje[1]) == $selectedmodel)
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='$onderdeeltje[0]'>$onderdeeltje[0]<br>";
    }
}
```

***Solved thanks to support from ZombieSpy.***

Comment: `file()` will still leave newlines at the end of each line, so it's actually `iPhone 3g\n` you're comparing against. the last line probably does NOT have a line break, so you actually do match.

Comment: Read my comments please on ZombieSpy's comment. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @KevinG: please don't add `[solved]` to the title. You've accepted an answer, that's all that's required. We can see that it's been solved from the home screen.

Comment: I see, noted. Would it not help for people searching for solved answers through google tho? :) It shows the page title but not the current state, that was more or less why i did it.

Comment: @Kevin G   Maybe change the title to something more related to the problem? Like "String in array from a file ain't what it is suposed to be" or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc B said, you might have the newline stuff, so use **str_replace**

```
echo "<form method='post' action='formpie.php'>";

$onderdelen = file("onderdelen.txt");

foreach ($onderdelen as $onderdeel) 
{
    $onderdeeltje = explode(",", $onderdeel);

    if (str_replace ("\n", "", $onderdeeltje[1]) == $selectedmodel)
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='$onderdeeltje[0]'>$onderdeeltje[0]<br>";
    }
}

echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Have tried this aswell based on Marc B's comment but it just does not want to work. Have tried both ways.. to str replace both onderdeeltje[1] aswell as $selectedmodel just in case since both come from lists.. but no go. Again it just shows the last one only :(

Comment: What's weird is that this exact same handling works in a foreach loop right above it, also with an exploded string split and read from a text file, why would this be a problem on this and not the loop before that? That one works just fine.

Comment: To shed some light about what i mean:

i have this exact code block above it getting models based on a selected model from a text file called models.txt, these are structured like this:
    modelname,brand

Comment: If you echo both sides, do they look the same?

Comment: Is there maybe a space in there that are evil? Try to remove all spaces in both strings

Comment: Yes, even without the str_replace statement when i echo both onderdeeltje[1] aswell as $selectedmodel i get a identical output. No \n tags or anything they look perfect that is why i am confused.

Comment: That could be it, the only difference from the models and the onderdelen.txt is that the models have brandnames after them split by a , that do not contain any spaces, the model names do but not the brandnames. This is different from the onderdelen.txt, they contain the model names (e.g. iPhone 3G) so there is a difference. I will try to change it to iPhone3G to see if this works.

Comment: You could just use **str_replace** on both sides

Comment: I already did, no go :( I also just now tried to make them identical to the way the models are being looped and it again just shows me the last one. There is no difference except for the loop showing a dropwdown box or these checkboxes. Am very confused as to why it is doing this. I am going to try to make iPhone 3G as a static variable and make a new single php form to see if this behaviour stays if its the only foreach loop on the whole page. * i removed all weird signs such as the euro's , dots and numbers aswell.

Comment: It keeps behaving like this on a single page;
    <?PHP
 
    $selectedmodel = "iPhone3G";
 
    echo "<form method='post' action='formpie.php'>";

    $onderdelen = file("onderdelen.txt");
 
    foreach ($onderdelen as $onderdeel) 
    {
      $onderdeeltje = explode(",", $onderdeel);
  
      if (str_replace ("\n", "", $onderdeeltje[1]) == $selectedmodel)
      {
       echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='$onderdeeltje[0]'>$onderdeeltje[0]<br>";
  }
    }
    echo "</form>";
    ?>

onderdelen.txt looks like this now:
    Reparatietouchscreen,iPhone3G
    etc..

Comment: And again, if i put echo $onderdeeltje[1]; in the loop, i get back "iPhone3G" 5 times, wich is the number of lines in the onderdelen.txt file.

Comment: Might there be a **\r** too in the list?  Windows uses **\n\r** as newline

Comment: I was searching along the answers you gave me about the evil spaces and decided to try and normally trim the output without even using the str_replace statement, and it started to work !:)

For some reason it seems to add a hidden space after the output in this foreach that i cannot see except for when i output them after eachother. Whenever i output them on a seperate line with for example <br> i do not see this extra added space. Anyways i will have to fiddle a bit more but i am sure this was the problem!
Thank you very much for your continued support mate!

Comment: Please put your solution in the question, so other that have similar problems also can find some help =)